# Safe to eat mac 'n' cheese the next day?

Tags: cheese, storage-lifetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

I've made mac and cheese. If I put it in the fridge (not freezer) in the original baking dish, covered with aluminum foil, will it be safe to eat the next day?

Is there a better way to store it for a day (better than covering with foil)?

Comment: My answer would only be anecdotal, so I'll leave it as a comment - I do this all the time with all sorts of casseroles and have never had a problem.

Comment: Is it ever safe to mac'n'cheese?

Comment: is this a troll question? I have successfully eaten mac and cheese that is two weeks old, the first day left overnight on the counter. Admittedly, though, in a cold climate.

Comment: No Doug, it's not a troll question. I've eaten mac & cheese only a couple of times and only on the same day. Given (my) complete lack of data on the subject, this seems like a good place to ask this information, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @KrzysztofKowalczyk As mentioned in the other question, basically *anything* cooked is safe to store for several days in the fridge. There's nothing special about mac and cheese. I think this is why Doug found the question odd - most people know that leftovers go in the fridge.

Comment: An "exact duplicate" of a question that asks a generic question where answer lists few items, none of which is mac & cheese? Since when all food items are equal wrt. to shelf life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your fridge is cold enough
You need to make sure your fridge is cold enough otherwise food poisoning bacteria will still be able to grow. Your fridge should be between 0ºC and 5ºC.

If you’re not sure how the temperature setting or dial works on your fridge, you could use a fridge thermometer to check it’s the right temperature.

Here are a few other fridge tips that you might find useful:

```
keep the fridge door closed as much as possible
wait for food to cool down before you put it in the fridge
if your fridge is full, turn the temperature down to help keep it cold enough
```

Cool leftovers as quickly as possible (ideally within one to two hours) and then store them in the fridge. Eat any leftovers within two days, except for cooked rice, which you should eat within one day to help avoid food poisoning.

Comment: -1 for the "one day" comment about cooked rice, which is nonsense.  Cooked rice isn't special and can easily be refrigerated for several days, just like everything else.  http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18723